# A Translation command

Tags: command, bots, discord, discord.js

I want to do a translation command. So when ppl willl type `y!translate <text>`, it will be translate to English language, and only.

Can I have a code for do that?

Thanks so much.

Comment: This question is too broad, lacks important details such as a D.js version, does not contain any code of your own on what you've already done and tried, and is simply asking users to write a large chunk of working code for you. I think you should break your problem down into steps and tackle each one individually. First look into making your bot register simple commands, then into extracting the user's query, then into Google Translate's API and how to use it, before making the bot respond with the result. From there, after trying but running into a roadblock, ask a more focused question.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot provide because it will be a big project you with code but maybe this is helpful.

Get a Google Translate API key:
https://cloud.google.com/translate

Read the Google Translate API documentation: 
https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/setup-basic

I can recommend you to use axios.js for node.js API requests: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

When a user types the command you'll need to do an API request and process the response and send it back in Discord.

If you would like to auto-detect the language you can take a look at this page:
https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/detecting-language-v3

I hope this was helpful for you, if not please let me know!